AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'samples'
Hi snakemake doesn't seem to recognize my wildcards in my rule modkit. i defined all possible outputs and assigned to a list modkit_outputs.
however, i get the error below and i'm not sure how to fix it.
Building DAG of jobs...
InputFunctionException in rule modkit in file //data1/greenbab/users/ahunos/apps/dorado_ont_wf/test_bedgraph.smk, line 29:
Error:
  AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'samples'
Wildcards:

Traceback:
  File "//data1/greenbab/users/ahunos/apps/dorado_ont_wf/test_bedgraph.smk", line 31, in <lambda> (rule modkit, line 40, //data1/greenbab/users/ahunos/apps/dorado_ont_wf/test_bedgraph.smk)

parent_dir = "/data1/greenbab/users/ahunos/apps/dorado_ont_wf/"
configfile: parent_dir + "config/config.yaml"
configfile: "/data1/greenbab/users/ahunos/apps/dorado_ont_wf/config/samples_009TN_044TN.yaml"

set_species = "human"

#make sample list of bedgraphs
motifs=["h", "m", "C"]
strands=["positive", "negative"]
minCoverages=[5, 10] 

samplesFromConfig=list(config["samples"].keys())#.tolist()
print(f"{samplesFromConfig}")


modkit_outputs = [
    f"results/modkit/{sample}/{sample}_{motif}_CG0_{strand}.bedgraph" 
    for sample in samplesFromConfig
    for motif in motifs
    for strand in strands
]

print(f"modkit outputs\n {modkit_outputs}\n")

rule all:
    input: 
        modkit_outputs

rule modkit:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.samples]
    output:
        outputs=modkit_outputs
    priority: 100
    params:
        reference_genome=lambda wildcards: config["mm10"] if set_species == "mouse" else config["hg38"],
        modkit_threads=16,
        modkit_prob_percentiles=0.1,
        outdir= "results/modkit/{samples}/"
    shell:
        """ 
modkit pileup --region chr17 --threads {params.modkit_threads} --bedgraph {input} {params.outdir} \
--prefix {wildcards.samples} --cpg --combine-mods --ref {params.reference_genome}

        """


You have sample (singular) in modkit_outputs, which you use in the output: for rule modkit, yet in the input you just have samples and the error says samples plural. Maybe look at here and make it sample = lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample] and fix params to be singular, too?

The shell part of your modkit rule contains a single modkit pileup command. Do you expect that one single command to process all of your samples in one go, or do you need Snakemake to run modkit pileup once per sample? I suspect the latter. If you can provide an example invocation of running modkit pileup and what specific files are created I should be able to tell you how to fix the rule. Also please show the output from your two print() statements. You clearly included these to help your own debugging and it would also help us here to see the results (you can redact if needed).

Your modkit_outputs in the output directive contains no wildcards.  They are all formatted in the list comprehension.  You should replace with the unformatted string: "results/modkit/{sample}/{sample}_{motif}_CG0_{strand}.bedgraph" in addition to staying consistent with sample and samples.
